# Keycloak returns CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am able to login to Keycloak using the `keycloak-js` client, however, when making a `fetch` request, I get the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/auth/realms/app_testing/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The post request I am making is

```
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append("client_id", 'vue_blog_gui');
formData.append("grant_type", "password");
formData.append("client_secret", "705669d0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4f4e52e3196b");
formData.append("scope", "openid");
formData.append("username", "user@example.com")
formData.append("password", "123")

fetch(
  'https://xxxxxxxx.com/auth/realms/app_testing/protocol/openid-connect/token',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: formData
  }
)
```

The keycloak settings are

- Root URL: `http://localhost:8080`
- Valid Redirect URIs: `http://localhost:8080`
- Base URL: `/`
- Admin URL: Empty
- Web Origins: `*` // but I have also tried `http://localhost:8080` and +

My app is running on http://localhost:8080

Comment: @dreamcrash I tried all your suggestions, but still, get the same CORS error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, btw it is not recomment to set Web Origins: to * because of security issues

Comment: Did you try already something as https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27FK.png ?

Comment: @dreamcrash I agree, but it was just to try and save people time asking if I had tried using * as the origin. LOL

Comment: I would avoid to using `localhost` for development. Some browsers may be very picky, even if you have configured it correctly (that's `http://localhost:8080` in `Web Origins`). I use my dev machine IP usually or I just enable `CORS everywhere` plugin in my Firefox during development (of course prod needs different proper secure setup).

Comment: BTW: direct access grant is not very secure auth approach. SPA (e.g. Vue) should be using grant code flow with PKCE (basic vue example but without PKCE https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue). I know that every SPA developer will told me that's better for him, because he will have own fancy SPA UI and not ugly Keycloak login form. Np, just keep in mind if your priority is UI or security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It was the format of the data I was sending to Keycloak. I need to URLEncode the FormData adding it to the body of the Fetch request. Also, was using `data` rather than `body` in the fetch request.

Anyway, I solved it by putting all the data into PostMan, getting it working in there and then taking the Auto Code generation that Postman provides to come up with this.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append('client_id', 'vue_blog_gui');
urlencoded.append('username', 'me@example.com');
urlencoded.append('password', 'password');
urlencoded.append('grant_type', 'password');
urlencoded.append('scope', 'openid');
urlencoded.append('client_secret', '705669d0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4f4e52e3196b');

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow',
};

fetch(
  'https://keycloak.server.example.com/auth/realms/app_testing/protocol/openid-connect/token',
  requestOptions
)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Nice that you have figured it out.

Comment: honestly -> you literally save my easter days, thanks! :D